# CQL equivalent of: select SYSTIMESTAMP from dual;?

Tags: database, cassandra, cql

How can I get current systime on Cassandra using DevCenter.

SQL: select SYSTIMESTAMP from dual;

CQL: ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT now() FROM system.local;
```

Comment: No luck, schema_keyspaces does not exist, in my setup.

Comment: Try `SELECT now() FROM system.local;`

Comment: Note that `now()` returns a [timeuuid](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/refDataTypes.html#refDataTypes__timeuuid).  If you want a more traditional date type, you'll need to convert it, e.g. `system.totimestamp(now())`

Answer (score -1):

I think Cassandra uses `now()`:

```
select now()
. . .
```

Comment: select now() from _what_ ?

Comment: If you are doing from DevCenter. Pick keyspace **system**. Afterwards try with this line of code: 
`SELECT dateof(now()) FROM system.local;`